# Display maximum of 4 icons a row in a dynamically generated component

Tags: html, css, angular

I am currently working on an emoji component based off of https://ngx-emoji-mart.netlify.app/.

I would like the component to take take up 100% of the parent div capacity and have a maximum of 4 items per row. What would be the best way of doing this? I have tried using flex-box but the issue is that I can't figure out how to limit the number of items per row.

My CSS code is as follows:

```
.emoji-anchor {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  color: #858585;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: color 0.1s ease-out;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.emoji-anchors {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px 0 25px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

The full code is quite lengthy to paste, so I have included it here: https://jsfiddle.net/2nxwpL8h/.

Bear in mind that the component is being created dynamically in Angular as follows:

```
<div class="emoji-anchors">
  <ng-template ngFor let-category [ngForOf]="categories" let-idx="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
    <span
      *ngIf="category.anchor !== false"
      class="emoji-anchor"
      (click)="this.handleClick($event, idx)"
      [class.emoji-anchor-selected]="category.name === selected"
      [style.color]="category.name === selected ? color : null"
    >
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path [attr.d]="icons[category.id]" />
      </svg>
      <span class="emoji-anchor-bar" [style.background-color]="color"></span>
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid with 4 equal columns

```css
.emoji-anchor {
  color: #858585;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 4px;
}

.emoji-anchors {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchors">

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M12 0a12 12 0 1 0 0 24 12 12 0 0 0 0-24m0 22a10 10 0 1 1 0-20 10 10 0 0 1 0 20M8 7a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4m8 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4m-.8 8c-.7 1.2-1.8 2-3.3 2-1.5 0-2.7-.8-3.4-2H15m3-2H6a6 6 0 1 0 12 0"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M15.5 8a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0-3m-7 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0-3m10.43-8h-.02c-.97 0-2.14.79-3.02 1.5A13.88 13.88 0 0 0 12 .99c-1.28 0-2.62.13-3.87.51C7.24.8 6.07 0 5.09 0h-.02C3.35 0 .07 2.67 0 7.03c-.04 2.47.28 4.23 1.04 5 .26.27.88.69 1.3.9.19 3.17.92 5.23 2.53 6.37.9.64 2.19.95 3.2 1.1-.03.2-.07.4-.07.6 0 1.77 2.35 3 4 3s4-1.23 4-3c0-.2-.04-.4-.07-.59 2.57-.38 5.43-1.87 5.92-7.58.4-.22.89-.57 1.1-.8.77-.76 1.09-2.52 1.05-5C23.93 2.67 20.65 0 18.93 0M3.23 9.13c-.24.29-.84 1.16-.9 1.24A9.67 9.67 0 0 1 2 7.08c.05-3.28 2.48-4.97 3.1-5.03.25.02.72.27 1.26.65A7.95 7.95 0 0 0 4 7.82c-.14.55-.4.86-.79 1.31M12 22c-.9 0-1.95-.7-2-1 0-.65.47-1.24 1-1.6v.6a1 1 0 1 0 2 0v-.6c.52.36 1 .95 1 1.6-.05.3-1.1 1-2 1m3-3.48v.02a4.75 4.75 0 0 0-1.26-1.02c1.09-.52 2.24-1.33 2.24-2.22 0-1.84-1.78-2.2-3.98-2.2s-3.98.36-3.98 2.2c0 .89 1.15 1.7 2.24 2.22A4.8 4.8 0 0 0 9 18.54v-.03a6.1 6.1 0 0 1-2.97-.84c-1.3-.92-1.84-3.04-1.86-6.48l.03-.04c.5-.82 1.49-1.45 1.8-3.1C6 6 7.36 4.42 8.36 3.53c1.01-.35 2.2-.53 3.59-.53 1.45 0 2.68.2 3.73.57 1 .9 2.32 2.46 2.32 4.48.31 1.65 1.3 2.27 1.8 3.1l.1.18c-.06 5.97-1.95 7.01-4.9 7.19m6.63-8.2l-.11-.2a7.59 7.59 0 0 0-.74-.98 3.02 3.02 0 0 1-.79-1.32 7.93 7.93 0 0 0-2.35-5.12c.53-.38 1-.63 1.26-.65.64.07 3.05 1.77 3.1 5.03.02 1.81-.35 3.22-.37 3.24"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M17 5c-1.8 0-2.9.4-3.7 1 .5-1.3 1.8-3 4.7-3a1 1 0 0 0 0-2c-3 0-4.6 1.3-5.5 2.5l-.2.2c-.6-1.9-1.5-3.7-3-3.7C8.5 0 7.7.3 7 1c-2 1.5-1.7 2.9-.5 4C3.6 5.2 0 7.4 0 13c0 4.6 5 11 9 11 2 0 2.4-.5 3-1 .6.5 1 1 3 1 4 0 9-6.4 9-11 0-6-4-8-7-8M8.2 2.5c.7-.5 1-.5 1-.5.4.2 1 1.4 1.4 3-1.6-.6-2.8-1.3-3-1.8l.6-.7M15 22c-1 0-1.2-.1-1.6-.4l-.1-.2a2 2 0 0 0-2.6 0l-.1.2c-.4.3-.5.4-1.6.4-2.8 0-7-5.4-7-9 0-6 4.5-6 5-6 2 0 2.5.4 3.4 1.2l.3.3a2 2 0 0 0 2.6 0l.3-.3c1-.8 1.5-1.2 3.4-1.2.5 0 5 .1 5 6 0 3.6-4.2 9-7 9"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M12 0a12 12 0 1 0 0 24 12 12 0 0 0 0-24m10 11h-5c.3-2.5 1.3-4.8 2-6.1a10 10 0 0 1 3 6.1m-9 0V2a10 10 0 0 1 4.4 1.6A18 18 0 0 0 15 11h-2zm-2 0H9a18 18 0 0 0-2.4-7.4A10 10 0 0 1 11 2.1V11zm0 2v9a10 10 0 0 1-4.4-1.6A18 18 0 0 0 9 13h2zm4 0a18 18 0 0 0 2.4 7.4 10 10 0 0 1-4.4 1.5V13h2zM5 4.9c.7 1.3 1.7 3.6 2 6.1H2a10 10 0 0 1 3-6.1M2 13h5c-.3 2.5-1.3 4.8-2 6.1A10 10 0 0 1 2 13m17 6.1c-.7-1.3-1.7-3.6-2-6.1h5a10 10 0 0 1-3 6.1"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M6.5 12a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5m0 3c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5s.2-.5.5-.5.5.2.5.5-.2.5-.5.5m11-3a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5m0 3c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5s.2-.5.5-.5.5.2.5.5-.2.5-.5.5m5-5.5l-1-.4-.1-.1h.6c.6 0 1-.4 1-1 0-1-.9-2-2-2h-.6l-.8-1.7A3 3 0 0 0 16.8 2H7.2a3 3 0 0 0-2.8 2.3L3.6 6H3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2c0 .6.4 1 1 1h.6v.1l-1 .4a2 2 0 0 0-1.4 2l.7 7.6a1 1 0 0 0 1 .9H3v1c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-1h6v1c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-1h1.1a1 1 0 0 0 1-.9l.7-7.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.3-2.1M6.3 4.9c.1-.5.5-.9 1-.9h9.5c.4 0 .8.4 1 .9L19.2 9H4.7l1.6-4.1zM7 21H5v-1h2v1zm12 0h-2v-1h2v1zm2.2-3H2.8l-.7-6.6.9-.4h18l.9.4-.7 6.6z"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M12 0a9 9 0 0 0-5 16.5V21s2 3 5 3 5-3 5-3v-4.5A9 9 0 0 0 12 0zm0 2a7 7 0 1 1 0 14 7 7 0 0 1 0-14zM9 17.5a9 9 0 0 0 6 0v.8a7 7 0 0 1-3 .7 7 7 0 0 1-3-.7v-.8zm.2 3a8.9 8.9 0 0 0 2.8.5c1 0 1.9-.2 2.8-.5-.6.7-1.6 1.5-2.8 1.5-1.1 0-2.1-.8-2.8-1.5zm5.5-8.1c-.8 0-1.1-.8-1.5-1.8-.5-1-.7-1.5-1.2-1.5s-.8.5-1.3 1.5c-.4 1-.8 1.8-1.6 1.8h-.3c-.5-.2-.8-.7-1.3-1.8l-.2-1A3 3 0 0 0 7 9a1 1 0 0 1 0-2c1.7 0 2 1.4 2.2 2.1.5-1 1.3-2 2.8-2 1.5 0 2.3 1.1 2.7 2.1.2-.8.6-2.2 2.3-2.2a1 1 0 1 1 0 2c-.2 0-.3.5-.3.7a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-.3 1c-.5 1-.8 1.7-1.7 1.7"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M0 0h11v2H0zm4 11h3V6h4V4H0v2h4zm11.5 6a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5m0-2.99a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .99c-.28 0-.5-.22-.5-.5s.22-.49.5-.49m6 5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5m0 2.99a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5.5.5 0 0 1 1 .01.5.5 0 0 1-.5.49m.5-9l-9 9 1.51 1.5 9-9zm-5-2c2.2 0 4-1.12 4-2.5V2s.98-.16 1.5.95C23 4.05 23 6 23 6s1-1.12 1-3.13C24-.02 21 0 21 0h-2v6.35A5.85 5.85 0 0 0 17 6c-2.2 0-4 1.12-4 2.5s1.8 2.5 4 2.5m-6.7 9.48L8.82 18.9a47.54 47.54 0 0 1-1.44 1.13c-.3-.3-.99-1.02-2.04-2.19.9-.83 1.47-1.46 1.72-1.89s.38-.87.38-1.33c0-.6-.27-1.18-.82-1.76-.54-.58-1.33-.87-2.35-.87-1 0-1.79.29-2.34.87-.56.6-.83 1.18-.83 1.79 0 .81.42 1.75 1.25 2.8a6.57 6.57 0 0 0-1.8 1.79 3.46 3.46 0 0 0-.51 1.83c0 .86.3 1.56.92 2.1a3.5 3.5 0 0 0 2.42.83c1.17 0 2.44-.38 3.81-1.14L8.23 24h2.82l-2.09-2.38 1.34-1.14zM3.56 14.1a1.02 1.02 0 0 1 .73-.28c.31 0 .56.08.75.25a.85.85 0 0 1 .28.66c0 .52-.42 1.11-1.26 1.78-.53-.65-.8-1.23-.8-1.74a.9.9 0 0 1 .3-.67m.18 7.9c-.43 0-.78-.12-1.06-.35-.28-.23-.41-.49-.41-.76 0-.6.5-1.3 1.52-2.09a31.23 31.23 0 0 0 2.25 2.44c-.92.5-1.69.76-2.3.76"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

  <span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor ng-star-inserted"><svg _ngcontent-urg-c146="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
            <path _ngcontent-urg-c146="" d="M0 0l6 24h2L2 0zm21 5h-4l-1-4H4l3 12h3l1 4h13L21 5zM6.6 3h7.8l2 8H8.6l-2-8zm8.8 10l-2.9 1.9-.4-1.9h3.3zm3.6 0l-1.5-6h2l2 8H16l3-2z"></path>
        </svg><span _ngcontent-urg-c146="" class="emoji-anchor-bar"></span></span>

</div>
```